# Transformed rows to columns SQL Server 2000/2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I am using SQL Server 2000. My table show data like when I issue SQL like

```
select * from mytable

TotalSale     RemanSale     DiagSale      TotalCall      CountryCode
----------    ---------     --------      ---------      -----------
16200           11100          5600          7                GB
15620           10100          4100          8                US
```

I want to show the above data like this:

```
Fields              Value       CountryCode
------              ------      ------------
TotalSale           16200           GB
RemanSale           11100           GB
DiagSale            5600            GB
TotalCall           7               GB
TotalSale           15620           US
RemanSale           10100           US
DiagSale            4100            US
TotalCall           8               US
```

If possible then also give me code in terms of SQL Server 2005 using pivot function.

First give me the code for SQL Server 2000 because I am using SQL Server 2000 and after that if possible then write down the same code for SQL Server 2005 using pivot function
thanks

Comment: This is **not** a "gimme ze codez" site - what have you **tried so far** ?? We're glad to help sort out any problems you might have - but we're not just writing code for you .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [pivot](http://www.tsqltutorials.com/pivot.php) feature, I think that would solve you're problem. For the SQL Server 2k you need to look into dynamic sql generation.